# i++ in xDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, loops

My program builds an html file from strings. I use xDocument for this (using System.Xml; using System.Xml.Linq)

Everything works nicely, but at some point I would like to add a loop that displays number to finish the while loop (1, 2, 3...) I marked the place in the code (**THIS PLACE FOR NUMBER**)

```
    var table_dynamic10 = new XElement("tr");
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        string query = string.Format("{0}{1}'", "SELECT ...");
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query , conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    table_dynamic10.Add(
                    new XElement("tr",
                    new XElement("td", new XAttribute("class", "tg-baqh")), **THIS PLACE FOR NUMBER**
                    new XElement("td", new XAttribute("class", "tg-baqh"), reader["SQL_Value"]),
                    new XElement("td", new XAttribute("class", "tg-baqh"))));
                }
            }
        }
    }

var xDocument = new XDocument(
                new XDocumentType("html", null, null, null),
                new XElement("html",
                    new XElement("head"),
                    new XElement("body",
                        new XElement("table", table_dynamic10))));
```

Comment: *"I would like to add a loop that displays number to finish the while loop (1, 2, 3...)"* - you are talking in riddles. Actually I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: for (i=0; i<reader.Read(); i++) <= o I would write 'for' in c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                int index = 1;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    table_dynamic10.Add(
                    new XElement("tr",
                    new XElement("td", new object[] {new XAttribute("class", "tg-baqh"),new XAttribute("index", index++)}), 
                    new XElement("td", new XAttribute("class", "tg-baqh"), reader["SQL_Value"]),
                    new XElement("td", new XAttribute("class", "tg-baqh"))));
```